# Would rather/had better in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech

Does there have to be a **backshift** of the infinitive used with WOULD RATHER/HAD BETTER in reported speech? I mean this:

> 1. I would rather *{meet}* him at 7 PM today.

- **reported speech**

> a) I said that I would rather *{meet}* him at 7 the same day.

- or

> b) I said that I would rather *{have met}* him at 7 the same day.

- another example

> 2 I was getting used to that, I suppose, but I would rather *{kiss}*
> her for the rest of the evening.

> 2a I was getting used to that, I suppose, but I would rather *{have
> kissed}*  her for the rest of the evening.

Comment: If the meeting hasn't happened yet, you can say "I said that I would rather meet him at 7 pm today." If the conversation being reported took place some time ago, it's "I said that I would rather have met him at 7 the same day."

Comment: Does that mean that they are lying here? https://www.grammaring.com/wish-if-only-would-rather-would-sooner-its-high-time-as-if-as-though-in-indirect-speech  Carol: I'd rather go by bike than walk.
Carol said that she would rather go by bike than walk.

Comment: "...I would rather kissed her..." doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, I'm sure they are not 'lying'. It seemed to me that the answer would depend on how long ago the conversation took place, but maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I agree with Kate that it depends whether the thing in question has happened yet. Example 1a could be a conversation in the past about a meeting in the future. Example 1b sounds like the meeting was scheduled for a time other than 7pm. Example 2 apples to an evening in progress; 2a applies to an evening in the past.